# Is there a way to preserve whitespace in an output of a Rest Parameter?

Tags: javascript

Whitespaces are not being preserved in the output of my function with a Rest Parameter

I have found a work-around, just declare the arguments with an initial space.
But it'd be nice to know if maybe I'm missing something, or maybe there's a better way to tackle this, or maybe that's just how it is.

```
function myFriends(greeting, ...friends) {
  console.log(`${greeting}, ${friends}`);
  console.log(greeting + ", " + friends);
}

myFriends("Hello!", "Ryan", "Zoe", "Jack");
myFriends("Hello!", "Ryan", " Zoe", " Jack"); //work-around
```

Comment: The whitespaces between the arguments are parts of the source code, not of the inputs to your function. `friends` is an array of the strings that you passed, nothing else.

Comment: Use `friends.join(', ');`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`friends` is an array. When you do `${friends}` (or `+ friends`), the interpreter tries to convert it to a string, by invoking the array's `toString` method, so that it can be concatenated. This joins all items by a comma (and no space).

It's trivial to explicitly join by a comma and a space instead:

```js
function myFriends(greeting, ...friends) {
  const friendsStr = friends.join(', ');
  console.log(`${greeting}, ${friendsStr}`);
  console.log(greeting + ", " + friendsStr);
}

myFriends("Hello!", "Ryan", "Zoe", "Jack");
```

Just to illustrate, you could also overwrite the `toString` method (but don't do this in real code):

```js
Array.prototype.toString = function() {
  return this.join(', ');
};
function myFriends(greeting, ...friends) {
  console.log(`${greeting}, ${friends}`);
  console.log(greeting + ", " + friends);
}

myFriends("Hello!", "Ryan", "Zoe", "Jack");
```